# Reporting vested and taxed RSUs on 2010 tax but unsold

Tags: united-states, income-tax, taxes

I received some RSUs in 2010 and I'm wondering how I should report these on my taxes. The RSUs were taxed when they were issued so there were some shares withheld for tax purposes. I did not sell any of my RSUs, but I'm wondering if I still need to report it.

Total shares issued - shares withheld for taxes = net shares issued

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to report anything besides what is reported on your W-2. Your company should have already included this as ordinary income in Box 1 and the respective taxes in the tax boxes. 
Please refer to this sample W-2 example below.

http://www.mystockoptions.com/image.cfm?img=/images/w2-RSU.gif